# What does the $t|y(x, \mathbf{w})$ in ${\cal N}(t|y(x, \mathbf{w}), \beta^{-1}) $ mean?

Tags: normal-distribution, notation

I'm starting to work through Bishop's "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning" book, and have run into unfamiliar statistics notation. In Eq. 160, Bishop writes the PDF for a quantity $t$ as

$$p(t|x, \mathbf{w}, \beta) = {\cal N}(t|y(x, \mathbf{w}), \beta^{-1}) \tag{1.60}$$

where $y(x, \mathbf{w})$ is some known function. Normally I'd expect this to be written as

$$p(t|x, \mathbf{w}, \beta) \sim {\cal N}(y(x, \mathbf{w}), \beta^{-1}) .$$

How should I interpret the $t|y(x, \mathbf{w})$ bit?

(Cross-posted from datascience.stackexchange.com; I figured it may be a better question for here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ambiguity.  In this book $N(t|\mu, \sigma^2)$ simply means the Gaussian functional form (see Eq (2.42) therein).  So $p(t|x, w, \beta) = N(y(x, w), \beta^{-1})$ simply means the density function of $t$ is Gaussian. Your expectation is more accurately fixed as $t|x, w, \beta \sim N(y(x, w), \beta^{-1})$.

Generally speaking, in probability/statistics, the notation "$\sim$" is used when the left side of it is a random variable $X$ (or a random variable conditioning on other random variables) and the right side of it is the probability distribution name (together with parameters) in terms of its mathematical shorthand, or equivalently, its cumulative distribution function $F$ (or density function $f$ if it exists. In more theoretical texts, could also be the distribution measure $\mu$).  For example, I am sure you have seen the notation $Z \sim N(0, 1)$, which means $Z \sim \Phi$ or $Z \sim \varphi$.  Under this simplified setting, Bishop's notation (1.60) actually tries to specify the density function of $Z$ is $p(t) = \varphi(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(t - \mu)^2}$.